# Why my focus() in jquery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the color of the text box in html when on focus. But my color is not changing.!

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Make a new account</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2 align="center" class="Heading">Want an account</h2>
  <h3 align="center" class="Heading">Enter your details</h3>
  <div align="center">
   <form name="Info_Form">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="TD">Your Name Pal :</td> <td><input type="text" name="Name"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="TD">Your Password :</td> <td><input type="password" name="pwd"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="right" ><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('h2').fadeOut(3000);
 $(".TD").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","blue");
  });
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: how can u focus 2 elements at the same time on a form??

Comment: @iJay He's trying to capture the focus event, not assign focus ;)

Comment: @Archer ahh....my bad ....was in a kind of rush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$(".TD").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","blue");
  });
```

Use:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","blue");
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you can apply `.focus()` to only a limited number of element (links, form inputs).

From [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) :

> The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event
>   is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form
>   elements (, , etc.) and links (). In recent
>   browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element
>   types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property. An
>   element can gain focus via keyboard commands, such as the Tab key, or
>   by mouse clicks on the element.

Here you try to apply it to a `<td>` tag.

Moreover, your `<input>` is not a child of `.TD`, so it's another problem in your code.

Why not simply use css `:focus` selector to achieve this ?